# Publish Feed - Facebook SDK 4.0

Tags: ios, facebook

I have integrated by iOS APP FBSDK 4.0. I have used

```
 FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];

    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"basic_info"] fromViewController:nil handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

        if (error)
        {
            [[AlertView sharedAlert] showAlertWithTitle:kAlertError Message:@"Login Error.Try after sometme" CancelButton:kAlertOKButtonTitle OtherButtons:nil];
        }
        else if (result.isCancelled)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login Cancelled");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",result.grantedPermissions);
            [self handleFBLoginResult];
        }
    }];
```

to login using FB and this step generates an access token which doesn't have publish permissions.

Then in other part of the app, when the user taps on publish to FB action, I am calling below method

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
[login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] fromViewController:topController handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

    if ([[result declinedPermissions] containsObject:@"publish_actions"])
    {
        [[AlertView sharedAlert] showAlertWithTitle:kAlertWarning Message:@"Publish Permission Denied.Please check your FB profile settings" CancelButton:kAlertOKButtonTitle OtherButtons:nil];
    }
```

Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

declined permissions is set to nil
granted permissions is set to nil
user cancellation action is set to YES , whereas I haven't cancelled anything

Looks like my permissions are not getting set and I am not able to post any feeds

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" parameters:postDict HTTPMethod:@"POST"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                         NSLog(@"%@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString]);

                        if(error == nil)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Checkin Posted");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //NSString *errMessage = [[[[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"error"] objectForKey:@"message"];
                            NSString *errMessage = [error localizedDescription];
                            [[AlertView sharedAlert] showAlertWithTitle:kAlertError Message:errMessage CancelButton:kAlertOKButtonTitle OtherButtons:nil];

                        }
                }];
```

This code above is failing to post the feed in FB and throws error message

Facebook error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action.

I am gone through some solutions mentioned but it didn't help me.

Any suggestions would be helpful.